# How to handle a failed PHP assertion with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, assert, assertions

I have an assertion in my code. Something like:

```
assert('is_string($var)');
```

If I write a test for PHPUnit that causes this assertion to fail with the message, `Warning: assert(): Assertion "is_string($var)" failed in /path/to/file.php on line ###`

And, my test also fails. I've tried adding `@expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` to the docblock [according to the documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors), but that doesn't help. What do I need to do to make my test expect that this assertion will fail?

Comment: Don't . Use . Assertions . In . Production

Comment: Why not include assertions in your code and in production just set `assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 0);` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [php.net/assert](http://nl.php.net/assert):

> Assertions should be used as a **debugging feature only**. You may use them for sanity-checks that test for conditions that should always be TRUE and that indicate some programming errors if not or to check for the presence of certain features like extension functions or certain system limits and features.
>
> Assertions should **not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks**. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.

So for normal code logic, use a boolean or some pre-defined constants. For exceptional logic use normal `if` statements and throw an `Exception` for invalid input.

If you are **really** keen on keeping the asserts, you could define an assert callback which throws an `Exception` you can catch in PHPUnit.

```
// PHP 5.3 Anonymous function as callback
// code is untested
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, function($file, $line, $code) {
    throw new Exception('Assert failed in $file on line $line');
});
```

Comment: I dont't see argument, why not use assertions at normal runtime. Surely, assertions shouldn't be used to check input parameters e.g., but to ensure, that the normal application state is still valid. Thus, they can be used to check for logical consistency.

Comment: Why not just throw an Exception manually when your function fails? The PHP Manual clearly says assertions are for debug purposes only. Its a tool to help you test your code in development, but should never be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Assertions should only fail when a test fails.

Comment: What if you need to test if the assertion fails?

Comment: @Joe: What do you mean? Assertions are how you _implement_ tests. So you want to test the test? :) At some point you have to rely on your colleagues and on code review. Unit tests should be small enough and close enough to your specified requirements that errors in unit tests are very difficult to make.

Comment: I'm talking about using an `assert()` in the function that I want to test with a unit test. I guess maybe it is a little redundant.

Comment: @Joe: It just seems like a really silly thing to want to do. Sorry. Your assertions should be in your unit tests and you should not use them anywhere else, ever. Why are you so dead set on using an `assert()`?

Comment: assertions should be everywhere you think they are useful. Furthermore, you might be testing someone else's code that may or may not have asserts, and you want to test that the asserts work as expected. The idea that asserts should not be used outside of unit tests is absurd. The OP's question is valid, and unanswered as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidWalley: _"assertions should be everywhere you think they are useful"_ Vacuous. Of course they should be where you think they should be. A meaningless statement meant only to distract. _"you might be testing someone else's code that may or may not have asserts, and you want to test that the asserts work as expected"_ That's a very good point. I'll take it. _"The idea that asserts should not be used outside of unit tests is absurd"_ I never made this claim. _"The OP's question is valid"_ Nobody said that it isn't. _"and unanswered as far as I can tell."_ Write an answer then.

Comment: My comment was not meant to distract. I know, I was there at the time.